# Let $\{X(t)\}$ be a Poisson process with arrival rate $\lambda>0$. Compute the conditional probability, $P(X(s) = x|X(t) = n)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

I am really struggling with the Poisson Process. I am hoping someone out there can give me few hints or point me in the right direction with the following exercise.

> Let $\{X(t)\}$ be a Poisson process with arrival rate $\lambda>0$. Consider a "bridge" for this Poisson process. It is known that a Poisson process, $\{X(t)\}$, has initial value $X(0) = 0$. Suppose it is also known that $X(t) = n$ for some $t > 0$ and $n$ a positive integer. Consider the probability function for a fixed earlier time point s such that $0<s<t$.
>   (a) What are the feasible outcomes for $X(s)$?
>   (b) Compute the conditional probability, $P(X(s) = x|X(t) = n)$.
>   (c) For a fixed s with $0<s<t$. State the conditional distribution of $X(s)|X(t) = n$ and hence check whether the result in (b) is a valid probability function. (Check over the feasible outcomes specified in (a)).

While I am having trouble with how the Poisson process works in general, here are my thoughts so far

For part (a) we have some interval $\zeta=(0,t]$ and a smaller interval $\xi=(0,s]$ such that $\xi\subseteq\zeta$. I believe we want all the possible outcomes for $\xi.$ This means all outcomes greater than $t$ are not feasible? This leads me to conclude that the feasible outcomes are given by
$$s_0,s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n.$$

However, this does not feel very concrete to me.

For part (b) we want to solve the conditional probability $P(X(s) = x|X(t) = n).$ Here let us denote $P(X(s) = x$ by our interval $\xi$ and $X(t) = n)$ by our interval $\zeta$. So we want to find $P(\zeta|\xi)$. However, since the time between each event is indecent we need only find $P(\xi)$. Is this correct so far?

Also, when actually doing the calculation do I use
$$P(n,\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda=0}\dfrac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}.$$

Somehow if feels to me as though I do not have enough information, which usually means I am missing a component of the question.

For part (c) I am confused about stating the conditional distribution. How is this different from part b. As for showing it is a probability function, I believe I just need to show my equation in part (b) is nonnegative and sums to zero.

Thank you all in advance you help and suggestions with this one. i am so far completely lost with this exercise.

Comment: Nice exercise statement. Where is your contribution?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) The tell you that by time $t$, $X(t) = n$. In other words, you could say there have been $n$ arrivals by time $t$. What are the possible values of $X(s)$?

(b) If there are $n$ by time $t$, and you want $x$ by time $s$, then how many must occur in between $s$ and $t$? Can you say something special about these two events? Are they disjoint? Independent?

(c) Name the distribution found in (b), and check against the possible values of (a).

---

(a) Since there are $n$ occurrences by time $t$, then the possible 
values of $X(s)$ are
$$\{0,1,2,\dotsc,n\}$$
since $X(s)$ is counting the number of arrivals by time $t, 0< s<t$.

(b) Notice that
$$\{X(s) = x, X(t) = n\}\iff \{X(s) = x, X(t)-X(s) =n-x\},$$
$X(t)-X(s)\sim\text{Pois}((t-s)\lambda)$, and that $X(s)$ is independent of $X(t)-X(s)$.

Then we proceed as usual, assuming some $\lambda >0$,
\begin{align*}
P(X(s)=x|X(t) = n)&=\frac{P(X(s) = x,X(t) = n)}{P(X(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X(s) = x, X(t)-X(s) =n-x)}{P(X(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X(s) = x)P( X(t)-X(s) =n-x)}{P(X(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{e^{-s\lambda}\frac{(s\lambda)^x}{x!}\cdot e^{-(t-s)\lambda}\frac{[(t-s)\lambda]^{n-x}}{(n-x)!}}{e^{-t\lambda}\frac{(t\lambda)^n}{n!}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\cdot\frac{s^x(t-s)^{n-x}}{t^x\cdot t^{n-x}}\\
&=\binom{n}{x}\left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^x\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)^{n-x}.
\end{align*}

(c) This is a binomial distribution
$$X(s)|X(t) = n\sim\text{Binomial}(n, p = s/t).$$