# Given a Poisson process $N(t)$ with rate $2$, find $P( N(3) = 4 | N(1) = 1 )$.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Given a Poisson process $N(t)$ with rate $2$, find
>   a. $P( N(3) = 4 | N(1) = 1 )$
>   b. $P( N(1) = 1 | N(3) = 4 )$

Using the method, I have

$$\frac{P( N(3) = 4 \cap N(1) = 1 )}{P( N(1) = 1)}$$
$$P( N(1) = 1) = 2 / \exp(-2)$$

Then because $P( N(3) = 4 \cap N(1) = 1 )$ is independent, therefore
$$\frac{P( N(3) = 4 ) P( N(1) = 1 )}{P( N(1) = 1)} = P( N(3) = 4 )$$

Am I correct in saying this for the first a?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's false, they are ***not*** independent.
Notice that
$$\{N(3)=  4, N(1) = 1\}\iff\{N(1) = 1,N(3)-N(1) = 3\}$$
and 
$N(1)$ is independent of $N(3)-N(1)$. Hence
\begin{align*}
P(N(3) = 4|N(1) = 1) &= \frac{P(N(3) = 4,N(1) = 1)}{P(1) = 1)}\\
&=\frac{P(N(3)-N(1) = 3, N(1) = 1)}{P(N(1) = 1)}\\
&=\frac{P(N(3)-N(1) = 3)P(N(1) = 1)}{P(N(1) = 1)}\\
&=P(N(3)-N(1) = 3)
\end{align*}

Comment: The reason why P(N(3)=4,N(1)=1) = P(N(3)−N(1)=4,N(1)=1) is because N(t) has independent increments?

Comment: I don't think so. The equality of the events is logical. I does not have to do with independence. The independence is due to the fact that you are dealing with disjoint intervals.

Comment: I see, thanks! Also, is " P(N(3)−N(1)=3) " a typo? Shouldn't it be  P(N(3)−N(1)=4) ?

Comment: I did make a typo, but no. It is correct now. Draw a picture and let me know if you still don't get it.

Comment: Also, consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.

Comment: @xx53xx For part b), try to use a similar argument. It would help if you drew a picture (in general a picture would help). If you need more details, a full explanation can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705366/let-xt-be-a-poisson-process-with-arrival-rate-lambda0-compute-the-c).

Comment: @xx53xx Oh, and if you find my other answer useful, please up vote. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!