# ($N_t$) is Poisson process with $\lambda = 1$. Calculate $E(N_2\mid N_1)$ and $E(N_1\mid N_2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, expectation, poisson-process

> ($N_t$) is a Poisson Process with constant rate $\lambda = 1$.
>   $1)$ Calculate $E(N_2\mid N_1)$:

So this is how far I've gotten:

Let $N_2 = N_1 + (N_2  - N_1)$

$E(N_2\mid N_1) = E(N_1\mid N_1) + E(N_2 - N_1\mid N_1) = N_1 + E(N_2 - N_1)$

But then I get stuck and I am not sure how to proceed.

> $2)$  Calculate $E(N_1|N_2)$:

First find conditional distribution of $N_1$ given $N_2 = n$

$$E(N_1\mid N_2 = n) = g(n)$$

$$E(N_1\mid N_2) = g(N_2)$$

But I get stuck here as well and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Notice that $N_2-N_1\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda(2-1) = \lambda)$. Hence $$E[N_2-N_1] = \lambda(1) = \lambda.$$
2. You should know by now, or recognize that $N_1|N_2=n$ follows a binomial distribution
   $$\text{Bin}(n, p = 1/2).$$
   You can show this by finding 
   $$P(N_1 = k|N_2 = n)$$
   using Bayes' rule.
   Hence $$E[N_1|N_2] = \frac12N_2.$$

Comment: If you need a detailed explanation for part 2, see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705366/let-xt-be-a-poisson-process-with-arrival-rate-lambda0-compute-the-c/1705371#1705371). If you find that one useful, consider up voting it. Thanks.