# For a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Compute the conditional probability, $P(X(s) = x | X(t)=n)$, given $s > t$.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I saw a post discussing this question, but the condition given is that $0<s<t$.
[Let $\{X(t)\}$ be a Poisson process with arrival rate $\lambda>0$. Compute the conditional probability, $P(X(s) = x|X(t) = n)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705366/let-xt-be-a-poisson-process-with-arrival-rate-lambda0-compute-the-c)

If the condition is changed to $s > t$, will it make any difference?

I would think that having $s>t$ makes the two events independent, but I am not sure. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct about independence: $x-n$ events occurring after time $t$ has nothing to do with what happened before $t$. So:$$
P(X(s) = x | X(t)=n)=P(X(s-t)=x-n)
$$